# Decode SQ_FETCHBLOB in Informix-Protocol

Tags: informix

I'm writing a parser for the SQLi-protocol ("turbo") used by Informix. I have most opcodes covered by now, yet `SQ_FETCHBLOB` I don't have a clue yet. Reverse engineering the driver is difficult since it copies values from its internal state machine, which itself is hard to track. All I know is that `SQ_FETCHBLOB` is followed by 56 bytes of data, some of which seem to be the BLOB's total size and fetch-offset.

Does anyone have some information on how to decode `SQ_FETCHBLOB` as used by Informix SQLi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on the specifics of the `SQ_FETCHBLOB` SQLI packet type but you might want to look at the file `$INFORMIXDIR/incl/esql/blob.h` which is shipped with Client SDK. This describes the `tblob_t` data structure which is 56 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. Could you drop the struct definition here? The CSDK I have does not include `incl/esql` or any other place where `blob.h` is.

Comment: I would probably be breaking all sorts of rules if I posted that structure directly here. The incl/esql directory should be included with all versions of CSDK so if it's not present in your install it may be that you have Informix Connect installed instead.

Comment: I also found the tblob_t structure is listed in some older versions of the Informix Administrator's Guide. For example page 43-60 of the v7 guide (found at ftp://ftp.uni-potsdam.de/pub/WWW/netscape/livewire/InformixDoc/ifmx_adm_2.pdf#page=1&zoom=auto,-13,731) shows it - note the figure is missing the "long tb_start" element positioned after tb_tblspace (this represents the starting byte).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if those fields are in the same order as they are on the wire, yet this is a start.